# How do I change/remove styling (top border) on main menu for active page and hovering (Avada Theme)

Tags: menus, child-theme, css

As per the title, how do I change/remove styling (which is a white top border) on the main menu for both the active page and on hovering a menu item? I am using the Avada child theme and started out with the Architecture demo content. I'm new to web dev and using Custom CSS but can figure most things out with a little guidance. Have checked the forum for existing threads but nothing I have tried has works so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put your own css properties to change styling. Use google inspection tool (f12) to check in which class you need to change properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to you theme admin panel then Appearance > Editor. Then paste this code bellow into Stylesheet (style.css):

```
.fusion-main-menu .current_page_item > a {

    border-color: #000 !important;
}

.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Hope it solve your problem

Comment: Will that code also work if I paste it in the Avada > Theme Options > Custom CSS area?

Comment: yes it will work fine